# Program is reading txt file but ignoring the if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, try-catch

I have to read a txt file using file-dialog. It works for me but I have an if statement which should ignore ("/"), blank lines and ("["). The if-statement is not working, output is just the original data in txt file, how can I fix it.  Below is the full method.

I'm expecting the data of txt file to be without "/" and "["

```
public void readToolData() { Frame myFrame = new Frame(); FileDialog fileName = new FileDialog(myFrame, "Open", FileDialog.LOAD); fileName.setDirectory("/"); fileName.setVisible(true);

if (fileName != null) {
String filePath = fileName.getDirectory() + fileName.getFile();
System.out.println("selected file:" + fileName);
File fileData = new File(filePath);
    
 String typeOfData = "";

 try {
// reading the file line by line scanner
    Scanner read = new Scanner(fileData);
     while (read.hasNextLine()) {
String lineOfText = read.nextLine().trim();
System.out.println(lineOfText);
// checking non empty or non comment | added ! to the or condition
if (!lineOfText.startsWith("/") && !lineOfText.startsWith("[") || lineOfText.isEmpty())
{
typeOfData = lineOfText;
Scanner lineReader = new Scanner(lineOfText).useDelimiter(",");
Tool t = new Tool();
this.storeTool(t);
      } } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); } } else { System.out.println("Error! No file selected!"); } }
```

Comment: Could you add an example input and output?

Comment: Due to ugly formatting it's hard to see, but one closing curly bracket is missing.

Comment: // this is a comment, any lines that start with //
// (and blank lines) should be ignored

[ElectricTool data]
// data is toolName, toolCode, timesBorrowed, onLoan, cost, weight, rechargeable, power
Makita BHP452RFWX,RD2001,12 , false,14995,1800,true,18V
Flex Impact Screwdriver FIS439,RD2834,14,true,13499,1200 ,true,10.8V
DeWalt D23650-GB Circular Saw, RD6582,54,true,14997,5400,false,1350W
Milwaukee DD2-160XE Diamond Core Drill,RD4734,50,false,38894,9000,false,1500W
Bosch GSR10.8-Li Drill Driver,RD3021,25, true,9995,820, true,10.8V. the output i

Comment: @unknownb please edit your question and add an example input to there instead of a comment. Nobody wants to to figure out where are line endings for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file in question looks something like this:

```
// this is a comment, any lines that start with //
// (and blank lines) should be ignored
[ElectricTool data]
// data is toolName, toolCode, timesBorrowed, onLoan, cost, weight, rechargeable, power
Makita BHP452RFWX,RD2001,12 , false,14995,1800,true,18V
Flex Impact Screwdriver FIS439,RD2834,14,true,13499,1200 ,true,10.8V
DeWalt D23650-GB Circular Saw, RD6582,54,true,14997,5400,false,1350W
Milwaukee DD2-160XE Diamond Core Drill,RD4734,50,false,38894,9000,false,1500W
Bosch GSR10.8-Li Drill Driver,RD3021,25, true,9995,820, true,10.8V
```

A regular expression or two would work well (I made a couple of other minor changes too):

```
public void readToolData() {
    Frame myFrame = new Frame();
    FileDialog fileName = new FileDialog(myFrame, "Select the file to load", FileDialog.LOAD);
    fileName.setDirectory("/");
    fileName.setVisible(true);

    if (fileName.getDirectory() != null && fileName.getFile() != null) {
        String filePath = fileName.getDirectory() + fileName.getFile();
        System.out.printf("Selected file: %1$s\n", fileName);
        
        File fileData = new File(filePath);
        String typeOfData = "";
        try {
            // pattern for lines to be skipped
            Pattern ptrnSkip = Pattern.compile("(?:^//|\\[)+?.*$");
            // pattern for line delimiter - account for potential leading / trailing spaces
            Pattern ptrnDlim = Pattern.compile(" *, *");

            // read the file line by line
            try (Scanner scnrFile = new Scanner(fileData)) {
                while (scnrFile.hasNextLine()) {
                    String lineOfText = scnrFile.nextLine().trim();

                    // skip empty lines and comments
                    if (!lineOfText.isEmpty() && !ptrnSkip.matcher(lineOfText).matches()) {
                        System.out.printf("Line read: \"%1$s\"\n", lineOfText);
                        typeOfData = lineOfText;
                        try (Scanner scnrLine = new Scanner(lineOfText).useDelimiter(ptrnDlim)) {
                            String strDesc = scnrLine.next();
                            String strCode = scnrLine.next();
                            int iBorrowedCount = scnrLine.nextInt();
                            boolean bIsOnLoan = scnrLine.nextBoolean();
                            int iCost = scnrLine.nextInt();
                            int iWeight = scnrLine.nextInt();
                            boolean bIsRechargeable = scnrLine.nextBoolean();
                            String strPowerSrc = scnrLine.next();
                            
                            System.out.printf("    Description: %1$s\n", strDesc);
                            System.out.printf("    Code: %1$s\n", strCode);
                            System.out.printf("    Borrowed count: %1$d\n", iBorrowedCount);
                            System.out.printf("    Is on loan?: %1$s\n", bIsOnLoan ? "yes" : "no");
                            System.out.printf("    Cost: %1$d\n", iCost);
                            System.out.printf("    Weight: %1$d\n", iWeight);
                            System.out.printf("    Is rechargeable?: %1$s\n", bIsRechargeable ? "yes" : "no");
                            System.out.printf("    Power source: %1$s\n", strPowerSrc);

                            Tool t = new Tool();
                            // do something with data here
                            this.storeTool(t);
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.printf("Line skipped: \"%1$s\"\n", lineOfText);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file selected");
    }
}
```

The [Apache Commons CSV library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) is nice for reading delimited data.  [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv) is a short intro if you're interested.